# Would Adipose Derived Stem Cells Reinjected into Fat Tissue Reorganize into their typical structure?

Tags: stem-cells

I've read papers saying that mesenchymal stem cells (and in some cases stem cells in general) retain a degree of tropism for their sites of origin based on epigenetic memory. Is that mechanism strong enough to suggest that adipose derived stem cells purified from lipoaspirate would reorganize into their typical structure within fat tissues if they were reinjected subcutaneously into fat tissue? When I say "typical structure", I'm referring to the uniformly distributed pattern [observed here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Structure-of-adipose-tissue-AT-is-composed-of-a-collagenous-background-together-with_fig2_264551515). Also, would cells injected in this way tend to spread out uniformly, or clump around the injection site? Or would that depend on how they were administered?